# How do I check keypoint matches in opencv (python)?

Tags: python, opencv, feature-detection, orb

My question is, how do I check the match rate of the keypoints that are matched through ORB? The code I'm using here is :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
img1 = cv2.imread('Vegeta4.png',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('Vegeta5.png',0) 

orb = cv2.ORB_create()

kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)


bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)


matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:7], flags=2, outImg = 
None)
plt.imshow(img3), plt.show()
```

I want to somehow show the match rate of the lines that connect the key points, and then based on that percent make a statement which can return True or False based on a certain threshold.

result of code - 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjS6l.jpg

Please do help, thanks.

Comment: What does "match rate" mean?